# The `source_files` pattern did not match any file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

What's the right way of pointing to the source files in case of private pod? 
I want to create my own pod, but can't solve the issue with *source_files* proper mentioning.

Here's how I do it now:

> s.source_files = "PromocodeTest/**/*"

And here are they ways I've tried, but nothing worked

> s.source_files = "PromocodeTest/Source/*.swift"
>
> s.source_files = "PromocodeTest.{h}"

Here is how my project is setup

[image]

Every time I run *pod spec lint* I get the above mentioned error: **[iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.**

Help me solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You usually would have a folder structure as this one when you create your own private POD (check it through Terminal or Finder):

```
 - Example
 - README.md
 - PromocodeTest.podspec
 - LICENSE
 - PromocodeTest
   |- Classes
   |- Resources
 - _Pods.xcodeproj
```

As you can see there should be a `PromocodeTest` folder which contains exactly two subfolders namely `Classes` and `Resources`.

Given that your `.podspec` or in this example the `PromocodeTest.podspec` would look like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'PromocodeTest'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'PromocodeTest summary description'

  s.homepage         = 'https://bitbucket.org/privaterepo/promocodetest'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'PrivateAuthor' => 'private.author@company.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:privaterepo/promocodetest.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'

  s.source_files = 'PromocodeTest/Classes/**/*'
  s.resources = 'PromocodeTest/Resources/Assets/*.xcassets'

  s.ios.frameworks = 'UIKit'
end
```

PS: In case you are not able to set it up correctly, try again to create a pod project from the beginning and try it following this [guide from CocoaPods using Pod Lib Create](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create) which should automatically create those Classes and Resources folder for you and link them correctly in the configuration of your pod project (namely `.xcodeproj`)